# To be Lyapunov stable solution and don't be stable solution asymptotically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the parameters  $ a, b \in R $  of equation $$ y''' + ay'' + by' + y = 0 $$ to the function $ y = e^{-x} $ be Lyapunov stable solution and don't be stable solution asymptotically?

Am I correct?

---

**My try follows**

1. f(x) - the quotient solution of the DE - = $e^{-x}$;
2. y(x) - the common solution of the DE - = $e^{-x}g(x) = e^{-x}c_1 + \cdots$;

Lyapunov stability: $$ \forall E>0 \exists d>0 \exists x_0 : |y(x_0) - f(x_0)|<d, \forall x>x_0 \Rightarrow |y(x) - f(x)|<E $$
Asymptotically non-stable solution: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{|y(x) - f(x)|} \ne 0 $$

---

$$K^3 + a K^2 + b K + 1 = 0$$
$$K_1=-1; K_1^3 + a K_1^2 + b K_1 + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow b=a.$$
For the stability every $Re(K)$ must be below zero.
$$K_1=-1,K_2-?,K_3-? < 0$$

1. $(K+1)(K^2+(a-1)K+1) = 0$
   $$K_{2,3}=\frac{(1-a) \pm \sqrt{(a-1)^2-4}}{2}$$

   - $K_2,K_3 \in \Bbb R$
     $$\frac{(1-a)}{2} < 0 \Rightarrow a>1; (a-1)^2 \ge 4 \Rightarrow a \ge 3$$
     $$K_2,K_3 \le \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx {-1.5}$$
     $$y(x) = c_1e^{-x} + c_2e^{K_2x} + c_3e^{K_3x} = e^{-x}g(x);$$
     $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{|g(x)-1|}{e^x}}=0$$
     $$\forall K_2,K_3,c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \Bbb R $$

     ### There is no solution.
   - $K_2,K_3 \in \Bbb C$
     $$3>a>1$$
     Take a look the quotient case:
     Let a=1 then $K_{2,3}=\pm i$
     $$ y(x) = c_1e^{-x} + c_2\cos{x} + c_3\sin{x} $$
     $$ |y(x_0) - f(x_0)|=|c_{2,0}\cos{x_0} + c_{3,0}\sin{x_0}|<d, \forall x>x_0 \Rightarrow |c_{2,0}\cos{x} + c_{3,0}\sin{x}|<E$$
     $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{|c_2\cos{x} + c_3\sin{x}|} \ne 0 $$
     and do not exist.
     **Therefore, if b=a=1 the quotient solution $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is Lyapunov stable and non-stable asymptotically.**
     $$3>a\ge 1$$

     ### There is a solution.
2. $(K+1)^3 = 0$
   $$ y(x) = e^{-x} (c_1 + c_2x + c_3x^2) = e^{-x}g(x) $$
   $$ |y(x_0) - f(x_0)|=|c_{1,0} + c_{2,0}x_0 + c_{3,0}x_0^2 - 1|e^{-x}<d, \forall x>x_0 \Rightarrow |g(x_0) - 1|e^{-x}<E$$
   But from the otherside, there are no $c_1,c_2, c_3 \in \Bbb R$ to $ \lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{|g(x)-1|}{e^x}} \ne 0 $, because $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} = 0 \forall n \in \Bbb R^+ $$

   ### There is no solution.